# Excel 2007 Ribbon

Tags: excel, vba, ribbonx

I have a simple Ribbon with a few groups in it.

I need to modify this ribbon through VBA to toggle visibility on the groups that I have in the Ribbon.  Let's say Range("A1") has "A" as the cell value; then this group would be visible.  If it's empty then it will be hidden.

Here is the XML for that Ribbon, the group I need to toggle is:

```
<group id="rxGrp_DeveloperTools" label="Developer Tools">
```

Comment: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s2/win012.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this markup for the ribbon group:

```
&lt;group id="rxGrp_DeveloperTools" label="Developer Tools" getVisible="rxGrp_DeveloperTools_GetVisible"&gt;
```

Then use a sub like this one to show/hide the group:

```
Sub rxGrp_DeveloperTools_GetVisible(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef bVisible)

    Dim sht as Worksheet
    Set sht = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)

    If sht.Range("A1").Value = "A" Then
        bVisible = True
    Else
        bVisible = False
    End If

End Sub
```